Performance degradation in GridDB TimeSeries with increasing dataset size
I'm currently exploring GridDB's TimeSeries functionality for storing and retrieving timestamped data efficiently. During my experimentation, I've noticed a performance degradation issue as the size of my dataset grows. Initially, queries were executing swiftly, but as more data was added, the response times increased significantly.
While examining my indexing strategies, I didn't notice any apparent flaws. However, I suspect there might be optimizations or best practices I'm overlooking to maintain consistent query performance as the database scales. Can anyone provide insights or recommendations on how to address this performance degradation issue with GridDB's TimeSeries feature?
